# Data Import Wizard for Contacts, prevent duplicates?

Tags: contact, field-update, data-import-wizard, duplicate-management

I'm importing a CSV file with about 2500 contacts from another system, outside of SalesForce. The wizard is matching based on name. So if I import the same spreadsheet again, the data doesn't update, but instead it creates duplicates. The data I am importing has a unique User ID field that is 8 characters long. But after reading for a while online, I found out that External ID field cannot be used for the default Contacts. What is the best way to prevent duplicates when importing bulk data? The imports would happen once a month and this is for non-profit organization, so it has to be free if 3rd party plugins will be needed. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apex data loader is the best. You can do all the functions using data loader. I guess you are using Enterprise edition with NPSP so data loader will work for you.

Comment: I read about it and tried it on a test computer. For some reason it does not allow me to login, and I know what my username/password is. Figured maybe I'm not allowed to used that functionality.

Comment: You need to append your security token after your password. Make sure that your org is a enterprise eddition, to know that place your mouse pointer on the tab for a little while it will show you the edition.

Comment: So there is no other way? It's kinda of lame to get duplicates if inserting the exact same data. It should be matched the same way by the wizard. I'm sure I can figure out the Data Loader, but that requires installing on your machine and not sure if my non-tech savvy client can handle it after I hand off the system :)

Comment: Data import wizard is much more complicated then data loader, in data loader you can save the field mapping and reuse it every other time. while in data import wizard u need to map every time we use it. for client a short training session is more than enough i suppose .

Comment: I had to reset my token and was able to login with Data Loader. I guess it needs the user to install another app, but does what it needs. Thanks!